# Spring caching ehcache issue

Tags: caching, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I have problem to set up properly caching for ehcache, Spring boot 1.5.2

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class CacheTestConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    factory.setShared(true);
    return factory;
}
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" 
dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<cache name="pujcka" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
    eternal="false" 
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
    transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>

</ehcache>
```

PujckaCachingRepository .java

```
public interface PujckaCachingRepository extends CrudRepository<Pujcka, Integer> {
    static final String CACHE_MAME = "pujcka";

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key = "#id", condition = "#id != null") // each calling select into DB - not cached
    //@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key = "#id", condition = "#id == null") //IllegalArgumentException Popis: Null key returned for cache operation 
//@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
Pujcka findOne(Integer id);

@Override
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
Iterable<Pujcka> findAll();

@Override
    //@CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key = "#pujcka.id") //URL: http://localhost:8081/pujcka/nova Vyjimka: SpelEvaluationException Popis: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
@CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
<S extends Pujcka> S save(S pujcka);

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
default void refreshAll() {
    //This method will remove all 'products' from cache, say as a result of flush API.
}
```

}

Pujcka.java

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Getter @Setter
public class Pujcka implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1385887062145410511L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

PujckaController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("pujcka")
public class PujckaController extends RootController {

@Autowired
private PujckaCachingRepository pujckaCachingRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "nova", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ulozPujcku(@Valid Pujcka pujcka, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    pujckaCachingRepository.save(pujcka);
    pujckaCachingRepository.refreshAll();
    return "redirect:/pujcka/seznam";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "seznam", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String seznam(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pujckaList", pujckaCachingRepository.findAll());
    return getRequestPath();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "edit/id/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    Pujcka pujcka = pujckaCachingRepository.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("pujcka", pujcka);
    return "pujcka/nova";
}
```

When I refreshing http://localhost:8081/pujcka/seznam at first call are featched data from DB and in second call are used this data from cache. This is working fine.

When I refreshing http://localhost:8081/pujcka/edit/id/1, each time is called DB and cache is not working. ---WHY????--- What am I doing wrong?

When I edit data and save it, select all is fired and list is updated, next refresh is populated from cache - that's working fine

With this settings is used cache, but in a cache are old values

```
   //@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
   Pujcka findOne(Integer id);
```

Thanks for help

---

UPDATE 1 - this helps, thanks jmw5598

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key = "#p0")
Pujcka findOne(Integer id);

@CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key="#result.id")
<S extends Pujcka> S save(S pujcka);

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
default void refreshAll() {
}

@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME)
Iterable<Pujcka> findAll();
```

in controller

```
pujckaCachingRepository.save(pujcka);
pujckaCachingRepository.refreshAll();
```

I removed refreshAll() method and tried to edit some rows. For calling findOne(id) is cache working, but for findAll() is not updated, so I return refreshAll() method back.

Is this correct or is there any way how to update cache in findAll() after editing item and calling save(pujcka) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Spring Data JPA, I don't believe you can reference the parameters directly by their names.  You can use SpEL metadata to reference the parameters though.

```
@Override
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key = "#p0", condition = "#p0 != null")
Pujcka findOne(Integer id);
```

also for the `@CachePut` you can use the result metadata item to reference the result objects id (or whatever field you want to use as the key).

```
@Override
@CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_MAME, key="#result.id")
<S extends Pujcka> S save(S pujcka);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context